# one way bookmark syncing/syncing issues Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, sync, bookmarks

I have two computers, a desktop computer that I use for nearly everything, as well as an old laptop that I only use when traveling. As a result of this the bookmarks on the laptop are outdated and often get screwed up and I don't want this to interfere with the bookmarks on my desk top.

Is there anyway to have the sync become one way so that it would cause the laptops bookmarks to match the desktops and not the other way around? Or will I have to turn off the syncing to preserve the bookmarks on my desktop as many of then were accidentally deleted on the laptop.... I fear that the laptop has overridden the bookmark sync so that when I go back to my desk top it will delete all my newer bookmarks (as well as the hundred or so that got deleted).

Comment: Use [Xmarks](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xmarks-bookmark-sync/ajpgkpeckebdhofmmjfgcjjiiejpodla)

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe there's a way to setup what you are calling "one-way syncing" of bookmarks.  Perhaps the best workaround for you is to not use sync, and just manually copy the bookmarks which you want to share on machines.

I haven't run into the problem you are describing with Chrome deleting bookmarks, myself.  In fact, I've hit the reverse problem, that Chrome Sync occasionally seems to duplicate bookmarks, so I wind up with 7 copies of the very same bookmark.